# GNU find: get absolute and relative path in -exec

Tags: bash, find, string, command-substitution, brace-expansion

I have a command (not `echo`!) that I want to run which takes an absolute path and a relative path.

How do I get these two arguments?

Attempt:

```
d=/tmp/foo;
find "$d" -type f -exec bash -c 'echo d=${1:${#d}} 1="${1%/*}"' bash {} \;
```

(I like GNU find because it's recursive, can restrict by file, can filter by filename, and doesn't spawn excessive shells)

Expectation:

```
mkdir -p /tmp/foo/bar/can/haz; touch /tmp/foo/bar/can/haz/bzr.txt
# cmd is run, output is:
d=bar/can/haz 1=/tmp/foo/bar/can/haz
```

Comment: and what should be the output if there would be file `/tmp/foo/file.txt` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Export `d`, then it will be available in your `bash` inline script. You also don't need `bash` at all here. Your (hopefully slimmer/faster) `sh` would do as well. Also, you don't need to run one shell per file. You can pass more files to your inline script with the `-exec cmd {} +` variant:

```
d=/tmp/foo
export d
find "$d" -type f -exec sh -c '
  for file do
    relative=${file#"$d/"}
    dir=${file%/*}
    relative_dir=${relative%/*}
    relative_dir=${relative_dir:-.}
    printf "%10s: %s\n" full "$file" \
                        relative "$relative" \
                        dir "$dir" \
                        reldir "$relative_dir"
  done' sh {} +
```

Which gives:

```
      full: /tmp/foo/bar/can/haz/bzr.txt
  relative: bar/can/haz/bzr.txt
       dir: /tmp/foo/bar/can/haz
    reldir: bar/can/haz
```

But if you only need the relative path, it may be simpler just to do:

```
(cd -P -- "$d" && find . -exec sh -c 'for file do...' sh {} +)
```

That would also make the command arguments passed to `sh` shorter so would allow `find` to pass more arguments to `sh`.

Note that there's nothing GNU-specific in your `find` command nor mine. That should work in any POSIX-compliant `find` implementation, not only the GNU one. The only non-POSIX part in your question was obviously `bash` and the `${1:offset}` operator which is a Korn shell operator, not in POSIX `sh`.

For a recursive file lookup that allows you to specify the file type, see also `zsh`:

```
(cd -P -- "$d" &&
  for file (**/*(ND.)) {
    dir=$file:h
    printf '%10s: %s\n' relative $file reldir $dir
  })
```

Above, the `.` is the equivalent of `find`'s `-type f` (only regular files), while `D` is to also include hidden ones like `find` does.

---

As a side note, in the general case:

```
c=$a$b; d=${c:${#a}}
[ "$b" = "$d" ] && echo yes
```

Is not guaranteed to output "yes", because the `${#var}` and `${var:offset}` operators work with *characters*, not *bytes*.

For instance in a UTF-8 locale, it would not output yes with these values of `a` and `b`:

```
a=$'St\xc3' b=$'\xa9phane'
```

With those, `$c` would contain my first name (`Stéphane`) `$a` contains half of that `é` character and `$b` the other half, `${#a}` would be `3` (2 characters and 1 byte not forming a valid character but still counted).

So `$d` would be `phane`, not `$'\xa9phane'`.

In the specific case of `d=$a/$b` though, it should be OK, as none of the character set generally available in system locales would have a character other than `/` that contains the encoding of `/`.

Comment: If d is a relative value (assume ` . ` while pwd is /tmp/foo) the result of absolute paths gets distorted. Maybe `d` should be pre-transformed to absolute.